# Problem in getting checkbox values using jsp-servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I am using jsp with servlet. I am showing values into checkbox by fetching it from mysql database table 'category'. but after fetching the values, I want to select some values and send them into other database table. But every time, I got an error "Cannot read the array length because "products" is null". I am not getting any values using 'request.getParameterValues("productName")'. so unable to send the selected values to other tables.

```
    This is my sample code: 
    
    **add_product_to_category.jsp**
    
<%@page import="java.sql.DriverManager"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.ResultSet"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Connection"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.PreparedStatement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.Statement"%>
<%@page import="java.sql.SQLException"%>

<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
String connectionUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";
String database = "stationaryapp";
String userid = "root";
String password = "...";
try {
    Class.forName(driver);
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Connection connection = null;
Statement statement = null;
ResultSet resultSet = null;
%>
        <body>
        
            <form action="ValidateProducts" method="post" id="addProductTocategoryForm"> 
        
        <table id="t01" class="table table-striped table-bordered"
                                    style="width: 100%">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Product ID</th>
                                            <th>Product Name</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <%
                                        try {
                                            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionUrl + database, userid, password);
                                            statement = connection.createStatement();
                                            String sql = "select * from products";
                                            resultSet = statement.executeQuery(sql);
                                            int i = 0;
                                            while (resultSet.next()) {
                                                String taskId = resultSet.getString("id");
                                        %>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td><%=resultSet.getString("id")%></td>
                                             <td><input type="checkbox" name="productName"
                                                value="<%=resultSet.getString("product_name")%>"><%=resultSet.getString("product_name")%>
                                            </td> 
                                        </tr>
                                        <%
                                        i++;
                                        }
                                        connection.close();
                                        } catch (Exception e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                        }
                                        %>
        </tbody>
                                </table>
                            </div>
                            <br>
                        </fieldset>
                        <br>
        
                        <button type="submit" class="addProductCategory" name="Submit"
                            value="Add Product To Category">Submit</button>             
                        <br>
        </form>
        </body>
    
    **Validate.jsp**
    
    public class Validate extends HttpServlet {
    
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    
        public Validate() {
            super();
        }
    
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
                throws ServletException, IOException {
    
            response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    
            PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();
            String products[] = request.getParameterValues("productName");
    
            try {
                String product = "";
                for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
                    product = product + "" + products[i] + ",";
                }
                printWriter.println("Products Selected Are : " + product);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                printWriter.println("The Error Is : " + e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
    
    **web.xml**
    
    <servlet>
            <servlet-name>checkboxProducts</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>login.Validate</servlet-class>
        </servlet>
        <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>checkboxProducts</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/ValidateProducts</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the call to `request.getParameterValues("productName")` returns null, that means that there is not a single checkbox checked when the form was submitted. According to [ServletRequest.getParameterValues](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues(java.lang.String)):

```
Returns an array of String objects containing all of the values the given request parameter has, or null if the parameter does not exist.
```

So you'll have to check for nulls after the call to `getParameterValues`.